# Why won't my array display in a webpage

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create an array with random, non-repeating numbers and store them in the array. However nothing is displaying right now. Perhaps I am missing something simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php
    $ranges = range(0,21);
    shuffle($ranges);
    foreach ($range as $ranger){
        echo$ranger;
        }

    $boxValues = array();
    $boxValues[0] = $ranger;
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: typo: `foreach ($ranges as $ranger)`

Comment: All will be revealed `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($ranges as $ranger){
```

not

```
foreach ($range as $ranger){
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from needing a space

```
echo $ranger;
```

while it may well still display, that is not a valid webpage. have a read here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp and place the content inside the body tags.

You have also not created a set of random numbers, you have just shuffled up a non-random sequence of numbers. Look at the [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function rather than range.

If it's a homework assignment, you probably need to solve the problem of picking random numbers but not reusing numbers already picked. There are a number of  different ways of solving the problem. You should encapsulate your solution in a function.